# the usage of “something starts from”?

Tags: verbs

I'm writing Personal Statement for Grad school. I wonder if it's correct to say "My passion for research starts from an early age?"

I didn't find problem at first, but then felt uncomfortable because passion itself can not behave itself and instead I should say "I started to have passion for research since an early age"?

But later I feel both are fine? Still confused.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: First, not the second. The first could also be "My passion...started..." depending on tense you're using in the rest of the personal statement.

Comment: I'd go with *began at* here.

Comment: **started from an early age**, otherwise it sounds like poor attempt at historical past.

Answer (score 1):

My passion for research started at an early age.
I have had a passion for research since an early age.

Study the usage of "Since" some more.